# Assistance with creating HTTP POST

Tags: html, xml, http-post

I have created a dynamic decision tree which is already exported to HTML. The last page produces a summary of the session. I will need help in exporting the session summary data to XML and submit it using HTTP POST method.

Comment: Add some more detail. What do you have (e.g. a string, some data structure?), what have you tried, and where are you getting stuck?

Comment: I honestly been researching online to no success -- not really familiar with XML and HTTP Posts. Need the data to send to S3 so I can use for reporting. I used AnswerPath to create the HTML file thinking that it will produce everything as they are advertising that their software is easy to use. Everything is provided HTML, CSS, and JS (which are embedded in the HTML file) but not how to export the data.

Comment: Already figured this out. The function to generate the XML file is already available in the file, just had to add a line to call that function.